# Addthis button not showing in backbone.js template

Tags: backbone.js, addthis

AddThis button is not showing in my backbone.js template.

I have the following code in my backbone.js template file:

```
            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook sharebtn"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_twitter sharebtn"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4 sharebtn"></a>
            </div>
```

and I put the following in the header file.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```

The header file is rendered using django templates.

What can I do?

Edit:

I tried putting this in the backbone template:

```
<div id = "toolbox"></div>
```

and then putting this at the end of the render function in the backbone view:

```
        tbx = that.$el.find("div#toolbox"),
            svcs = {email: 'Email', print: 'Print', facebook: 'Facebook',
                expanded: 'More'};

        for (var s in svcs) {
            tbx.innerHTML += '<a class="addthis_button_'+s+'">'+svcs[s]+'</a>';
        }

        addthis.toolbox(document.getElementById('toolbox'));
```

But addthis is still not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddThis` plugin script parse the HTML at the moment it is loaded. Your template is loaded asynchronously, as so, `AddThis` isn't finding the relevant markup to render the buttons.

What you need to do, is to call the `AddThis` rendering function once your template have been render to screen.

Checkout *Render with javascript* section of their doc: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api

Comment: Check out my edit in the post above. I am still having trouble.